# Returning two values from an enum list

Tags: java, arrays, enums

I have a list made using an enum command. I'm doing some coding exercises for java, and here I am asking the user for a colour. Depending on what colour is entered it will enter corresponding example values (variable names have been changed for the purpose of learning how to do this), it will return the example test word that relates to that colour.

In the first code segment below, I have achieved this, and if you input RED then testa is what you will get as an output.

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.EnumSet;

public class PLTypeEnum
{
    enum colours { RED, YELLOW, BLUE, GREEN }
    
    enum example { testa, testb, testc, testd}
    
    private static <E extends Enum<E>> E getEnumElement(String elementExample, Class<E> elementExampleName)
    {
        boolean haveResult = false;
        E result = null;
        Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        while ( ! haveResult )
        {
            System.out.print("Input " + elementExample + ": ");
            try
            {
                result = Enum.valueOf(elementExampleName, stdin.next().toUpperCase());
                haveResult = true;
            }
            catch (IllegalArgumentException e)
            {
                System.out.println("Not a valid " + elementExample + ".");
                stdin.nextLine(); // skip the invalid input
            }
        }
        
        return result;
    }
  
    private static colours PLType2pl(example plt)
    {
        colours name = null;
        
        switch (plt)
        {
        case RED:
            name = colours.testa;
            break;
        case YELLOW:
            name = colours.testb;
            break;
        case BLUE:
            name = colours.testc;
            break;
        case GREEN:
            name = colours.testd;
            break;
        }
        
        return name;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.print("Known colours = ");
        for (example t : EnumSet.allOf(example.class)) 
        {
            System.out.print(t + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        
        example plt = getEnumElement("colour", example.class);
        System.out.println(plt + " is of : " + PLType2pl(plt));
    }
}
```

But the issue i am having is that this code all goes wrong if for example, i wish RED to be associated with two values from example, lets say testa and testb, then this code does not work and i have tried so many different possibilities but i cant figure it out even though it should probably be very easy.... for example I would want to do something like this (but this results in an error)

```
 private static colours PLType2pl(example plt)
    {
        colours name = null;
        
        switch (plt)
        {
        case RED:
            name = colours.testa, colours.testb;
            break;
        case YELLOW:
            name = colours.testb;
            break;
        case BLUE:
            name = colours.testc;
            break;
        case GREEN:
            name = colours.testd;
            break;
        }
        
        return name;
    }
```

I have tried making "name" an array but when i do that then the value I get back is no longer "testa" and "testb" but rather a list of numbers and appears to be the memory address or something.

How can I tweak the first code segment to make it so that when red is input, then what returns is "testa" and "testb"? Also im new to this so please be precise

Comment: Return an `EnumSet`?

Comment: iterate and print the returned values . 
or System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.asList(yourenum.values()));

Comment: You may want to scrap this program and start over. Think what it is you want to achieve rather than try and make your existing code work. And please follow Java naming coventions so that other people may understand your code more easily.

Comment: Your input is `RED` or `testa`?

Comment: The code you provided (the part you claim to be working - 1 color -> 1 test) has compilation errors.

Comment: You are switching on `plt` for values `RED` which is not on the enum `example`. This code seems to be a mess, as others commented. Start from scratch and explain what you need. Your example code makes no sense. Voting to close as unclear.

Comment: the above code is part of a practice question for university, I have changed variable names but the structure of the code remains the same. I was told to make as few changes as possible and to make it return as described in the question

Comment: the input is a colour, so RED would be one

Answer (score 0):

This problem is actually easy to solve:

```
public enum Color {

RED(Arrays.asList("testa","tastb")),
YELLOW(Arrays.asList("testc","tastd","teste"));

Color(List colours){
    this.colours = colours;
}

private List<String> colours;

public List<String> getColours(){
    return this.colours;
}

  }



--------------test------------------

public class TestColor {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "RED";
    System.out.println(Color.valueOf(input).getColours().toString());
}
}
```

---------------output----------------

```
[testa, tastb]
```

Comment: Tip: In recent Java `List.of`